# UITableViewController crash on loading second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a project where I want to open a UITableViewController after a UITableViewController via a UINavigationController. The thing is, it works the first time when it gets called by this function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SDMetadataEntity *entity = [self.optionItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    SudzcDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[SudzcDetailViewController alloc] init];
    detailViewController.refName = entity.Name;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    [entity release];
}
```

But when I press the back button on the navigation bar, and press the same item again, it crashes! It doesn't crash when I press a different item in the first UITableViewController. I would really like to learn from what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Can you post the crash log? It could be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not

```
[entity release];
```

because when you do

```
[self.optionItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

you just fetching a pointer to it, not init/copy/retaining it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be releasing `entity`.

You got that object from an array, you don't own it, so when you release it you may be causing it to be deallocated prematurely.